# How to secure WPF application log files from tampering?

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, authorization

Application uses NLog to write log files to disk (and to a network storage). The problem is that if the WPF application can write the log file(s) then the user can read (and modify) them. This is obiously not desired behaviour.

How to prevent active directory users from accesing application's log files?

**EDIT:**

It is mandatory to store the logs as a text file for simplicity. Although, NLog could save to a database.
Encrypting log files could be optional.

What I am looking for is a concept how the application could write log (files) which are not accessible to the application users.

Comment: Why is it not desired behavior? If you have information in log files that should not be modified, then perhaps it should be stored elsewhere.

Comment: Put the files (or log to) somewhere where the users don't have access?

Comment: You could send the log entries to a database that the user doesn't have access to (either a local one with secret credentials, or a remote one the user can't see at all).

Comment: @mm8 The app is running under the user's credentials.

Comment: Not enough info in the question. Do you just want to sign the log entries with an encrypted checksum? Do you just want to store the logs encrypted? Do you want to store a separate copy of the logs encrypted? Or just blocks of data interspersed with the regular plain-text data? Many ways to skin a cat here.